# What exactly happens inside the OS to cause the segmentation fault

Tags: operating-system, segmentation-fault

I have read a lot about the virtual address and paging.
Let me first tell you people what i understood. When a process wants to execute something it tries to load the data from the hard disk to memory. To do this it uses a virtual address. So our MMU validates the virtual address looks into the TLB to find the corresponding physical page, if it doesn't find there it looks into Inverted Page Table and at the end it looks into Page table if it doesn't find an entry over there it generates a page fault and all the swapping of page is done and all the tables will be updated. 
And as I read all the processes have different page tables and same virtual address. so if I try access an array element a[1000] which was defined as int a[100] I am sure that am gonna get a segmentation fault cause that instruction might be trying to access a memory that doesn't belong to it. but how OS comes to know that a[1000] doesn't belong to the running process by just using the concept of virtual address and physical pages. Am I missing something here or my entire understanding is wrong?

I know we can say a memory access is illegal if a process is trying to access a read only or sup true memory segment.

at the end the boiling question is how OS decides which memory is allocated to which process and how it decides that this access of memory is illegal.

[What is a segmentation fault on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200526/what-is-a-segmentation-fault)

this link didn't help much .

thanks a lot in advance for all you lovely people's inputs :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually each and every process in the Linux kernel has some well defined structure associated with it called task_struct which stores all the information about the corresponding process like its parent, its PID, its child, its address space, pending signals, threads associated with it etc. Now the address space entries tell the kernel while executing the process the legal address space for that process.Every process has its own address space allotted to it by the kernel right from the very beginning when it is created. So when a executing process tries to access the space outside its legal memory a fault is generated(called segmentation fault in `Unix/Linux`) and the process is terminated by giving a signal to it by the kernel. Its important for memory protection to be achieved in OS.

Comment: thanks a lot for the input . But here, what we mean by address space? do we mean virtual address space ?could you please tell me little bit more about address space and memory is allocated to process in page by page manner right ?  and everyone tells paging is nice to have cause it provides the memory isolation and all, isnt that true ?

Comment: Yes, look in today's Os 2 things are Virtualized: processor & memory. So Its nothing to complicate about for current treat it just like any memory address space.As far as paging is concrned its just a way of lokking at the memory from kernel size. It helps in organizing memory for different puposes like DMA, normal execution. Actually, as kernel runs in kerenl mode so it has previllaged access to the hardware and hence some mechanism is needed to protect the user space process running in kernel space(like in executing a system call) from accessing any other kernel process address space.

Comment: But the deal is for all the process the virtual address starts at 0x08048000 for 32 bit processors and at 0x400000 for the 64 bit processors so it has to be same for the all of the processes right? the deal of running in the kernal space is handled by the dividing the virtual address space into kernal space and user space and not allowing processes to access any of the krenal space virtual address . but what about the protection between the 2 processes ? coz for all  the processes the virtual address is same and how do os make one process not access the memory of the other ?

Comment: +1 Some good information on where the virtual mapping is stored for a process.

Answer (score 1):

On x86, linux uses a combination of segmentation and paging, so the address generated by program first looks up for the corresponding segments base and limit registers values. This gives the virtual address which is then translated using the page table. When you try to access a memory which has not been allocated, the accessed page is beyond what the limit register allows, hence generating a segmentation fault.